# Implementing login activity in Android

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity

I'm developing an Android app which requires the user to be logged in (actually, at the moment they just need to supply a username as no authentication is required... this will change in the future though).

I've managed to implement this, but I'm not sure if it's the best way. I have a `LoginActivity` which I have declared in the manifest using `android:noHistory="true"` and:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In `LoginActivity`'s `onCreate` method, I check for a Boolean value `isFirstStart` stored in `SharedPreferences`. If the value does not exist, it must be the first start of the app, so I let `LoginActivity` set everything up, perform the login, and then launch `MainActivity` using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ISFIRSTSTART, isFirstStart);
startActivity(intent);
```

I use the extra so that I can open the navigation drawer in my main activity if it is the first start. At this stage I also store the Boolean value as `false` in `SharedPreferences`.

If `isFirstStart` already exists as `false`, I perform the launch of `MainActivity` straight away using the same method.

To me, this somehow doesn't seem like the most efficient method - launching `LoginActivity` on every startup even though it will not be used most of the time.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not starting MainActivity and if the isFirstLogin == true startactivityForResult the LoginActivity

Comment: I have though about this some time ago, and this is the login workflow I came up with : http://njzk2.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/login-activity-workflow/ Typically, the `loggedIn` value should be indeed kept in sharedPreferences in `LoginableActivity`.

Comment: @A.S. Yeah, I think that might be my best solution, however, there are some things I'm not sure about. In `MainActivity`, when I use `startActivityForResult`, the user is then able to press the back button from `LoginActivity` and get taken to `MainActivity`. I don't want them to be able to access `MainActivity` until they have logged in. I don't have a great understanding of Intent flags etc. so what will I need to do in order for the back button to simply exit the app from `LoginActivity`?

Comment: Yeah you could override the BackKey on your LoginActivity and then finish the app, or you could get the Result of LoginActivity in the MainActivity and if it is not the correct login finish the app. Just a few thoughts

Comment: Ok, I've had a play and actually ended up creating a new activity, `StartupActivity`, that does nothing apart from determine whether to launch MainActivity or LoginActivity. I think this will actually be the best solution for me, but thanks for all the input both of you.